# Creating split panel in react js

Tags: html, jquery, css, reactjs

I need to create split div functionality in reactjs. As shown in this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/d65&view/editor). this one is implemented in extjs. I want similar implementation is reactjs. We need to add grids on either side of split panel. I am short of ideas on how to implement it. Not looking for code, but need ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi you can check this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-split-pane) called react-split-pane. Also [there](http://react-split-pane-v2.surge.sh/?BasicVerticalPaneExample) you can find example for you case. Also [there](http://react-split-pane-v2.surge.sh/) others examples.